# Resource Dictionary Get X:Key or X:Name

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, ivalueconverter

I am trying to get the x:key or the x:name from a resource dictionary and I didn't manage to find a proper solution in order to achieve this.

My dictionary is defined something like this:

```
< ResourceDictionary x:Class="com.mycompany.WpfCore.ResourceDictionaries.ThemedControls"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    x:Name="TestName">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and I access it into a IValueConverter:

```
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     ResourceDictionary dic = value as ResourceDictionary;
     if (dico == null)
     {
        return "NaN";
     }
     else
     {
        return dico.GetType().Name;
     }
   }
```

Currently this code returns me "ThemedControls" name, but I would like to get the name from x:key or from x:Name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102504/access-resourcedictionary-by-name

Comment: I checked it out but is not what I need. I want to be able to retrieve dynamically that name from x:key or x:name without knowing the dictionary name. ( Like i showed in example for getting the "ThemedControls" )